# How to replace values of a column in MySQL table with another value

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table named as **data1** with two columns `(Name, address)` and an another table named as **data2** with same columns

My question:
How to assign the value as 'USA' to `address` column where the value in `name` columns are equal in both the tables.

Comment: What's wrong with `UPDATE`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams would you please write me the command with update?

Comment: @user2058811, what have you tried?

Comment: @theghostofc I have tried the below query

Comment: UPDATE data1 SET
data1.address = 'USA'
WHERE data1.name=data2.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE data2 SET
Address = 'USA'
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM data1)
```